# htpasswd not working when set up in the httpd.conf file

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, htpasswd

My `httpd.conf` file looks like:

```
<Directory "/path/to/mysite">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"
    Require user valid-user

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I generated my `.htpasswd` file using the `htpasswd` command: `$ htpasswd ~/.htpasswd myuser`

So now when I restart apache, it prompts for a username and password, however, when I type in my username and password, it just prompts again. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

My `.htpasswd` file looks like: `myuser:$aaa1$rsU3A8zu$1xiIou2elcL3QLIPhzsaj0`

Comment: What does your `~/.htpasswd` look like?  Feel free to obfuscate the password but it'd be good to check that the format is correct.

Comment: Edited my question to include contents of `.htpasswd`

Comment: What's in your apache logs?

Answer (score -1):

I am no Apache expert, so there may be other ways of doing this... Although the documentation states that it should work just fine..

But instead of having the `Auth` directives in a `<Directory>` block, try instead adding them to a `<Location /<insert location here>` block. Like this:

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile .htpasswd
    Require user valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Instead of `/`, should I use my path?

Comment: Path seen from the web servers side. Not `/var/www/html/secret`, but `/secret` if that is the page that the clients go to.

Comment: Tried that - negative

Comment: The difference between Location and Directory is that Directory is used for a place in the file system, whereas Location matches on the URL (whether or not that matches an actual place in the file system). Just switching from one to the other without an actual reason is very unlikely to be at all helpful.